# How to display the records from Kafka to console?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

I'm learning Structured Streaming and I was not able to display the output to my console.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
import org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.ProcessingTime

object kafka_stream {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    val spark = SparkSession
      .builder()
      .appName("kafka-consumer")
      .master("local[*]")
      .getOrCreate()
    import spark.implicits._

    spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel("WARN")

//    val schema = StructType().add("a", IntegerType()).add("b", StringType())

    val schema = StructType(Seq(
      StructField("a", IntegerType, true),
      StructField("b", StringType, true)
    ))

    val df = spark
    .readStream
    .format("kafka")
    .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "172.21.0.187:9093")
    .option("subscribe", "test")
    .option("startingOffsets", "earliest")
    .load()


    val values = df.selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING)").as[String]

    values.writeStream
      .outputMode("append")
      .format("console")
      .start()
      .awaitTermination()


  }


}
```

My input to Kafka

```
my name is abc how are you ?
```

I just want to display strings from Kafka to spark console

Comment: Why are you using `.outputMode("append")`? Any particular reason? Can you show how you send a message to Kafka? kafka-console-producer? You sure you use `test` topic? What's 9093?! I think it should be 9092.

Comment: As i mentioned in the question "My input to kafka" this is how i am sending input to kafka and i am using append because i want latest output

Comment: My understanding is that _""My input to kafka""_ is what you send to Kafka not how you do it. How you send can help us figure out why you see no output from the code. Append is the default so there's no point setting it up explicitly (unless you know why you're doing it). Remove unneeded things so we clean the code up and hopefully make it work.

Comment: Looks like it's just because you typed a wrong broker address. Kafka consumer will try forever if it cannot connect to the broker.

Comment: No it is properly connecting because when i do df.streaming() it is printing true

Comment: "df.streaming()"? Could you clarify it? There is no `streaming` method.

Comment: If you meant `isStreaming`, then the result means nothing except your DataFrame is a streaming DataFrame, and Spark won't connect to Kafka until you call `start()`.

Comment: But i am already calling start() method in my code